# Auto increment with prefix showing wrong after adding 1000 records

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have fields in the table which are id, name, employee_id. The id column is the primary key with auto increment.In this table,

I need one column which called `employee_id` start from `A5001, A5002, A5003...and soon`.

I tried below code.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE table1_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE table1
(
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  employee_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);
```

Now the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.employee_id = CONCAT('A', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 4, '500'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then just insert rows to table1

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (name) 
VALUES ('ABC'),('ZXD'),('POI');
```

Finally, I got my output.

```
1|ABC | A5001
2|ZXD | A5002
3|POI | A5003
```

and so on

Now My issue is, I inserted 1000 rows in the table so my id is 1000 but there is some issue with my employee_id because after getting the A5999 it starts from A1000 which is totally wrong I need continuously like `A6000, A6001, A6002.. and so on`

I think there is some issue with my trigger.

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: What's surprising in it? You told it to left-pad the ID with the string `'500'`, and that's what it's doing. The `'500'` is a fixed string and will never change. You need to add the ID to a number like 5000 if you want it to continue after 5999.

Comment: Oh! That I don't know @RacilHilan, Thank for the information. Any other idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Think about it 1000 already has 4 characters, so left-padding it will not have any effect and it will stay `'1000'`. While if you add 1000 + 5000 = 6000. There are other ways to solve it, but what's wrong with the addition? Why do you need another way? The answer that you have from Damian is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mathematical addition instead of string padding:

```
SET NEW.employee_id = CONCAT('V', 5000 + LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

**Explanation:**
I'm just adding 5000 to last insert ID. Think of it: 
1st ID would be 5000 + 1 = 5001
999th ID would be 5000 + 999 = 5999
1000th ID would be 5000 + 1000 = 6000

It will never throw an ID shorter than 4 digits, so there is no need of `LPAD`.

**Warning**: You have to think what do you want after 4999th insert. It will cause an ID of 5 digits (5000 + 5000 = 10000). If you don't have a problem with 5 digits, leave it this way.

Comment: Damian, your answer is good, but consider adding a brief explanation to make more useful for future readers. You can copy from my comments above and modify it, or write your own.

Comment: @Damain, Yes, Thank you , It's working, perfectly, Hope I will not get any issue in this

Comment: @RacilHilan, Yes You are right it's hard to understand why it's working. I just copy and paste it. Why You removed LPAD?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I thought it was clear. I edited the answer.

Comment: @DamiánPabloGonzález, Yes, I don't have a problem. I need a number continuously. In future, it will be more than 10000 or 20000 records. It will increase the 5 digits. I hope I will not get any issue in your code.